# How to print double quotes around a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For instance, we have:

```
word = 'Some Random Word'
print '"' + word + '"'
```

Is there a better way to print double quotes around a variable?

Comment: If `word` contains double quotes of its own, do you want them to be escaped or left alone?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Update :**

From [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

```
>>> print(f'"{word}"')
"Some Random Word"
```

**Original Answer :**

You can try [%-formatting](https://pyformat.info/)

```
>>> print('"%s"' % word)
"Some Random Word"
```

OR [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples)

```
>>> print('"{}"'.format(word))
"Some Random Word"
```

OR escape the quote character with [`\`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

```
>>> print("\"%s\"" % word)
"Some Random Word"
```

And, if the double-quotes is not a restriction (i.e. single-quotes would do)

```
>>> from pprint import pprint, pformat
>>> print(pformat(word))
'Some Random Word'
>>> pprint(word)
'Some Random Word'
```

OR like others have already said (include it in your declaration)

```
>>> word = '"Some Random Word"'
>>> print(word)
"Some Random Word"
```

Use whichever *you* feel to be better or less confusing.

And, if you need to do it for multiple words, you might as well create a function

```
def double_quote(word):
    return '"%s"' % word

print(double_quote(word), double_quote(word2))
```

And (if you know what you're doing &) if you're concerned about performance of these, see [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48465349/2689986).

Comment: None of these solutions (except maybe `pformat`?) handle the possibility of `word` containing a double quote.

Comment: @celticminstrel that's not true. *All* of these can entertain the possibility of `word` itself having double quotes. The content of `word` does not affect the ability of the methods to add double quotes around it. If someone does want only one pair of surrounding double quotes, then that's a somewhat different ask altogether.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough… I'm referring to escaping the quotes if necessary. If you don't care about that, then sure, these methods are all fine.

Comment: @celticminstrel I still don't understand why escaping the quotes would be required or may mess up wrapping the `word` around them. Could you please give a sample input & expected output?

Comment: Well, it depends on why you want to do this in the first place. If it's just for output, to be displayed to the user, then it likely doesn't matter (though having a random double quote in the middle would still be weird). On the other hand, if it's meant to be serialization, then escaping the quotes is essential. These are just examples of course.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. In that case one must use corresponding serializer library methods, like `json.dumps`, etc.

Answer (score 25):

How about `json.dumps`:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps("hello world"))
"hello world"
```

The advantage over other approaches mentioned here is that it escapes quotes inside the string as well (take that `str.format`!), always uses double quotes and is actually intended for reliable serialization (take that `repr()`!):

```
>>> print(json.dumps('hello "world"!'))
"hello \"world\"!"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try `repr`

Code:

`word = "This is a random text"
print repr(word)`

Output:

`'This is a random text'`

Comment: This is the perfect answer... unless you _really_ want double quotes specifically, in which case `json.dumps` is probably the better option.

Comment: The question was about printing double quotes around the value, which this does not do

Answer (score 6):

It seems silly, but works fine to me. It's easy to read.

```
word = "Some Random Word"
quotes = '"'
print quotes + word + quotes
```

Answer (score 5):

Using format method or f-string with repr(), you can write it more elegant.

```
a = "foo"
print("{!r}".format(a))
b = "bar"
print(f"{b!r}")
```

Comment: can you give link to documentation on this

Comment: You could see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: if you want equivalent to `fmt.Printf("value = %q\n", value)`, that what you need

Answer (score 4):

```
word = '"Some Random Word"' # <-- did you try this?
```

Answer (score -4):

Use escape sequence

Example:

```
int x = 10;
System.out.println("\"" + x + "\"");
```

O/P

```
"10"
```

Comment: OP is asking for Python, not Java