# Python(on Win10): Path issue replacing "\" with "/"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preface: I am a beginner to Python

Problem statement: I am writing a script wherein I will be launching an application (`Gotit.exe`) sitting at particular path lets say `D:\Some Folder\SomeMore Folder\AgainFolder\myPythonFolder\Gotit.exe`. I have kept the python-script also in `myPythonFolder`.

I am accessing the folder path via `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` and selecting particular application by appending it with `\Gotit.exe` but when passing the same appended string stored in a variable i.e. `GotitexePath` to `os.system(GotitexePath)` its throwing error as,

> 'D:\Some ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.**

Kindly help me out to solve the said issue

I am using python 3.8.2 on Win10 Machine

Comment: Please update your question with your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you have no slash issue, you have a blank issue, try double quotes around it

Comment: correct @Turo, I have tried below solution and it seems its not working for me, can you please point if I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

The error is pointing to `Some Folder` name. Since there is a space in path you provide, the system doesn't know whether it is a part of folder name or it is a next argument to the command.

You need to *escape* the blank space. There are multiple ways to to it. For example wrap the path with double quotes:

```
"D:\Some Folder\SomeMore Folder\AgainFolder\myPythonFolder\Gotit.exe"
```

For more ways see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks#)

Comment: Thanks for replying.Since the path is in variable not sure how to double-quote it, could you please suggest a workaround for the same ?

Comment: I have tried solution given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056548/printing-double-quotes-around-a-variable) , still same error

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("\"%s\"" % GotitexePath)
```

A the previous replies say, you need to add additional quotation marks around the path for the windows command line.