# Join a list of strings and number in python and wrap each string in quotation marks

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a list containing number and string:

```
words = ['hello', 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want a string:

`"'hello', 2, 3, 4, 5"`

What's the easiest way to do this with Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printing double quotes around a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056548/printing-double-quotes-around-a-variable)

Comment: What do you want to happen if another string is present? e.g. `words = ['hello', 2, 3, 'there', 5]`? And what if `words = [1, 2, 'hello', 4, 5]` Convert any string or just the first element?

Comment: `words = ['hello', 2, 3, 'there', 5]` This is also possible or 
`words = ['hello',' 2', '3', '4', '5']` In this one, I have to change first one which is not a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words = ['hello', 2, 3, 4, 5]
", ".join([str(x) if isinstance(x,int) else "'{}'".format(x) for x in words])
```

Output:

```
"'hello', 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `str.strip`:

```
str(words).strip("[]")
```

Output:

```
"'hello', 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Comment: A nice hack. Appreciate this answer

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, this is my solution:

```
words = ['hello', 2, 3, 4, 5]

result = '''"{}"'''.format(", ".join(map(lambda x: "'{}'".format(str(x)) if isinstance(x, str) else str(x), words)))

print(result)
```

Output is:

```
"'hello', 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
words = ['hello', 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(','.join([str(elem) if isinstance(elem,int) else "'{}'".format(elem) for elem in words]) )
```

Output :

```
'hello',2,3,4,5
```

Comment: The expected output is different

Comment: it not having `` for hello word. your one is perfect